# how to run the android phonegap application in background(after closing the application)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I have used the system notification plugin from the github(https://github.com/saileshmittal/phonegap-system-notification-plugin) for android phonegap.I have used this code in my index.html

My code is:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);


    function onDeviceReady() {
    var not_title   = 'Message';
    var not_text    = 'Zou dit werken?';
    var not_tText   = 'Message';

    navigator.systemNotification.onBackground();
    navigator.systemNotification.onForeground();
    navigator.systemNotification.createStatusBarNotification(not_title, not_text, not_tText); 
    }
```

I got the notification icon in both foreground and background.But is it possible to run the whole application to run in the background when the button is clicked in the application and call my **wcf** services continuously.Also i need to get the alert even when running in the background.how to do that?

`navigator.systemNotification.onBackground()`:this line run the application in background or not other wise it only for showing the notification after closing the application.

please guide me,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the phonegap documentation you cannot run the apps in the background, the js cannot continue to run. The reason notifications are able to work is because they are using the native system to send the notifications.

In order to make processes run in the background you will need to create a plugin that uses the native os.

Comment: how to use onPause (event) method in phonegap api for running application background. Is it possible or not ,If it is possible how to show alert while application running in background.please help me,thanks in advance.

Comment: Like i said js cannot be executed in the background, you can use the on pause to stop specific actions or to listen for onresume to happen. The only way you will be able to do anything in the background is to create a custom native plugin that does that work for you. As for the alert look into the localNotifications that will allow you to send notifications in the background

Answer (score 4):

I made an Android application with PhoneGap and when I press the home button, my application stays in background (with my last test it stays more than 1 hour). But when I launch other App the Android OS kills my application.

To enable this behaviour you need to add the android permission:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />` to your manifest

and you also need to add:

`<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />` to your `config.xml` in folder `res/xml`

I hope this post can you help you :)